# Pulumi GCP impossible to create a VPC private connection ip not found

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pulumi, pulumi-python

I'm using Pulumi to manage GCP infrastructure. I want to create a Cloud SQL instance with a private IP but it keeps failing stating :

> ```
>   error: 1 error occurred:Error waiting for Create Service Networking Connection: Error code 9, message: Allocated IP range 'dbprivip' not found in network.
> ```

I'm creating an Global address and trying to attach it to the Private Connection.
The ip exists

```
NAME             ADDRESS/RANGE  TYPE      PURPOSE                  NETWORK     REGION        
SUBNET  STATUS dbprivip         10.0.10.5      INTERNAL  PRIVATE_SERVICE_CONNECT  bastionvpc                        RESERVED
```

jumpserverpubip  34.155.83.36   EXTERNAL                                       europe-west9          IN_USE

Here's the code I have written:

```
db_ip_reserved_range = gcp.compute.GlobalAddress(
            "DbIpRange",
            name = "dbprivip",
            purpose = "PRIVATE_SERVICE_CONNECT",
            address_type = "INTERNAL",
            network = vpc_network.id,
            address = DB_PRIV_IP
            )
private_network_con = gcp.servicenetworking.Connection(
            "DbPrivateConnection",
            opts = pulumi.ResourceOptions(
                depends_on = [
                    db_ip_reserved_range
                ]),
            network = vpc_network.id,
            reserved_peering_ranges = [
                db_ip_reserved_range.name
            ],
            service = "servicenetworking.googleapis.com"
            )
```

I begin to wonder if that's not a bug in the pulumi_gcp provider.
I have tried with Terraform following the examples in the documentation and I have the same result.